# Sum numbers in filenames in a directory using command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I'd like to have a sum of real-time sales-tax exposure on my desktop. I name all my purchases and expenses the same way: date {string} SPACE item{string} SPACE amount{string}, the latter will always be a dollar and cents amount with a period separator. I'd like to add the numbers for amount in each filename in a directory.

Once I had a text file with the dollar amounts I'd probably process that in excel to work out the sales tax, which here is 15% on everything.

filename example:

```
20160516 jcca.15144 115.00 anRtn.pdf
20160408 DunPrint.poster 90.85 29725-1.pdf
20160505 bpSouth.fuel 59.71.jpg
```

I've searched on this and found no hits so is this even possible in windows command line?

Comment: Are these the only kind of files in a particular directory?

Comment: Yes they're in a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I create a text file with dollar amounts from the following filenames?

```
20160516 jcca.15144 115.00 anRtn.pdf
20160408 DunPrint.poster 90.85 29725-1.pdf
20160505 bpSouth.fuel 59.71.jpg
```

Use the following batch file (ExtractPrices.cmd):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b %1`)  do (
  for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ("%%~na")  do (
    echo %%b>>prices.txt
  )
)
```

Usage:

```
ExtractPrices directory
```

- `directory` is the name of a directory containing the files to process
- The dollar amounts are extracted from the filenames and written to `prices.txt` located in the same directory as the batch file.

Example output:

```
F:\test>dir /b files
20160408 DunPrint.poster 90.85 29725-1.pdf
20160505 bpSouth.fuel 59.71.jpg
20160516 jcca.15144 115.00 anRtn.pdf

F:\test>ExtractPrices.cmd files

F:\test>type prices.txt
90.85
59.71
115.00
```

---

#### Once I have a text file with the dollar amounts I'd probably process that in excel

This is a good idea. Although arithmetic can be done in batch files it is difficult and has limitations - it can only handle 32-bit integers.

However, there are workarounds if you really want to use batch files for the arithmetic.

See [Math in NT batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php) for more information.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Comment: Well done. However, I'd keep each sale identification for easy import to excel creating `.csv` file as follows: `for /f "tokens=1-3" %%b in ("%%~na")  do (
    echo "%%b","%%c",%%d>>prices.txt
  )`

Comment: @JosefZ Not a bad idea. Let's see what the OP thinks.

Comment: When I run that against:

- 20150406 bpTay.fuel 54.40.jpg
- 20150418 bpBal.fuel 28.95.jpg
- 20150418 BPsouthern.fuel 51.32.jpg
- 20150421 bpBal.fuel 42.50.jpg
- 20150501 bpBal.fuel 47.61.jpg
- 20150505 caltexSavoy.fuel 20.00.jpg
- 20150507 caltexSavoy.fuel 39.85.jpg
- 20150516 clintonExpress.fuel 25.99.jpg
- 20150521 BPsouthern.fuel 51.94.jpg
- 20150523 zmosgiel.fuel 57.22.jpg

I get this error
%%b was unexpected at this time.

Comment: The batch works perfectly DavidPostill, thanks very much, I'll go and try it out on some different directories and get back.